# MILP optimizer in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, portfolio

I am trying to do a minimum variance optimization with weights retrained to 1. I tried multiple solvers but they either take too long to compute or are imprecise, so I want to try using a MILP solver.
Here is my Objectif function :

```
library(Rglpk)

funct1 <- function(weight)  {
  t(weight) %*% covariance_matrix %*% weight
}
```

Constraint:

```
equality <- function(weight) { 
  a1 <- sum(weight)
  return(a1)
}

Rglpk_solve_LP(funct1,equality,c("=="),c(1))
```

I keep getting the error :

> Error in as.numeric(funct1) :
> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

I assume the error is there because of the function but how can I formulate the objective of the optimization without a function?

Comment: Does that help https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/Rglpk.pdf? Have a look at the structure iin the example. If you need further help, a reproducible example is needed.

Comment: The only missing data for a reproductible example would be a covariance matrix. One could use matrix(c(0.14 , 0.46, 0.5,0.45, 0.36, 0.42 , 0.32 , 0.23, 0.75), nrow=3) for example for the covariance matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quadratic model: the objective is `x'Qx`. That means you cannot use Rglpk, as that is for LPs and MIP models only (i.e. linear models).

You can have a look at CVXR which supports QP and MIQP models. Note that the best (fastest, most reliable) MIQP solvers are not open source solvers but rather solvers like Cplex and Gurobi (for academic users they may be free).